# Hotkey for offline simulating in the Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to test how my app works with offline mode. I want to either use airplane mode or set signal strength to none. However, I need to do it in the short moment, so it would be better to have a hotkey for that. Is there such hotkey in Android Emulator from Android Studio?

I'm using Android Studio 3.3.1 for Mac.